# Limiting number of pages on a paging list

Tags: coldfusion, paging

I am working on revamping a sites' paging system, and I have run into something simple I can't seem to solve. I am trying to show pages (1 2 3 4 5) at a time, and when the user gets to page 5, the list changes to something like (4 5 6 7 8). How could I do this using a cfloop? Here is a sample of my code:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#totalPages#" index="i">
<cfoutput><a class="paging" href="?start=#(i*25)-24#">#i#</a></cfoutput> 
</cfloop>
```

At the moment it shows pages 1 - 54 all at once. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres my code

```
<cfset curPage = Int(start / 25) + 1>

<cfloop from="1" to="#totalPages#" index="i">
  <cfif i is curPage>
    <div class="page current">#i#</div>
  <cfelse>
    <cfif totalPages lte 5 or i is 1 or i is totalPages or (i gt curPage - 3 and i lt curPage + 3) or ((curPage is 1 or curPage is 2) and i lt 6) >
      <div class="page"><a href="?start=#(i*25)-24#">#i#</a></div>
    <cfelse>
      <cfif i is 2 or i is totalPages - 1>
        <div class="more">...</div>
      </cfif>
    </cfif>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

What this code does is it shows the first 5 pages, then an ellipsis, then the last page. As you page through it, it will always show the link to the first and last page, plus 2 page before and after the current page.

Screenshots: Page 1 [image: Page 1] and page 10 [image]

You should be able to easily modify this to work exactly how you want it. (I happen to not like when all of the links change at once the way you described)

Comment: This looks great, thank you. I am having one issue with it though, what exactly should I define result and curpage?

Comment: sorry, i need to clean that up

Comment: I added the <cfset> for curPage variable. The 25 should be whatever number of items you display on one page. Theres no reason for the result variable, i removed it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great open source pagination library that will solve your problem. I can't say enough good things about it because *I wrote it*. Shameless, I know. Anyways:

http://www.dopefly.com/projects/pagination/

Check out the docs, they are very complete and helpful. In your code, printing the page numbers are as simple as calling `#pagination.getRenderedHTML()#`. It is pretty customizable so that you can change the numbers that are printed and you can style the output however you like.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<cfloop from="#url.startpage#" to="#url.startpage+4#" index="i">
  <cfif i LE totalpages>
    <cfoutput><a class="paging" href="?start=#(i*25)-24#">#i#</a></cfoutput> 
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Of course you would need to add "startpage" to your url and manipulate it appropriately. So your first link would be startpage=1 but your last would be startpage=4 (if I understand your question correctly).